# Subset data frame to only include the nth highest value of a column

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have a data frame abc and would like to subset the data frame to only include the row with nth highest value of a certain variable "z".  I know a simple solution here would be:

```
       library(plyr)
       abc <- arrange(abc, z)
       abc <- abc[n,]
```

But is there a way to do it without first ordering the data frame?  I'm only asking because ordering seems to be expensive on larger data frames.

Here's an example df to work with:

```
    x  y   z
1   2  1 111
2   3  2 112
3   4  3 113
4   5  4 114
5   6  5 115
6   7  6 116
7   8  7 117
8   9  8 118
9  10  9 119
10 11 10 120
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try

```
library(dplyr)
n <- 7
slice(abc, rank(z)[n])
```

Or as @nicola commented, a `base R` option would be

```
abc[rank(abc$z)==n,]
```

#### Update

If you want the nth highest with rank increasing

```
 slice(abc, rank(-z)[n])
 #  x y   z
 #1 5 4 114
 abc[nrow(abc)-rank(abc$z)+1==n,]
 #  x y   z
 #4 5 4 114
```

Comment: Or without `dplyr`: `abc[rank(abc$z)==n,]`.

Comment: For some reason my version of dplyr does not have the slide function.  I re-installed it to make sure it's up to date, but I'm getting an error?

Comment: @Ben I am using `dplyr_0.4.1.9000`  `slice` should be pretty fast

Comment: what do you think is more efficient with a large dataframe?  nicola's solution or the solution using slice?

Comment: @Ben Based on some previous benchmarks with `slice`, it is very fast, though haven't tested with nicola's version.

Comment: Maybe he is searching the nth highest and `rank` goes increasing. Maybe `abc[nrow(abc)-rank(abc$z)+1==n,]` is correct, if that is the case.